# How to use intents to open an activity that can have different ListView contents?

Tags: android

I am making an app that allows the creation of a gym workout schedule. My main activity includes a ListView (regular ArrayAdapter) with each item being a day of the week. When one item is clicked, a second activity is opened where there are EditTexts to enter the name and number of reps/sets for the exercise, as well as another ListView (custom adapter, called exerciseAdapter) for the exercises to be performed that day. There is also an Add button that adds the entered information of the exercise to the ListView. What I am trying to do is thatfor each different day that is pressed, there is a different displayed ListView of the second activity since there can be different gym schedules for different days of the week but my app currently shows the same schedule for any day pressed. I know that I need to use an intent to pass the position of the clicked ListView item, but I am not sure what to do with that intent in the second activity.

This is the code for my main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayList<String> daysOfWeek = new ArrayList<>();
    daysOfWeek.add("Monday");
    daysOfWeek.add("Tuesday");
    daysOfWeek.add("Wednesday");
    daysOfWeek.add("Thursday");
    daysOfWeek.add("Friday");
    daysOfWeek.add("Saturday");
    daysOfWeek.add("Sunday");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, daysOfWeek);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WorkoutActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("position", position);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

}

This is the code for the onCreate of the second activity:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_workout);

    dbExercises = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("exercises");

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    index = intent.getIntExtra("position", -1);

    exerciseNameET = findViewById(R.id.exerciseNameET);
    setsET = findViewById(R.id.setsET);
    repsET = findViewById(R.id.repsET);
    restTimeET = findViewById(R.id.restTimeET);
    addButton = findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    exerciseList = findViewById(R.id.exerciseList);

    exercises = new ArrayList<>();

    exerciseAdapter = new ExerciseList(WorkoutActivity.this, exercises);
    exerciseList.setAdapter(exerciseAdapter);

    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addExercise();
        }
    });
}
```

UPDATE: I have tried passing a string instead of an integer and using an ArrayList of exercises for each day of the week. Depending on the passed string value, I apply the corresponding ArrayList to the array adapter. However, no matter what day of the week that is clicked in the main activity, the same exercise schedule ListView appears in the second activity.

```
public class WorkoutActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String day;

EditText exerciseNameET;
EditText setsET;
EditText repsET;
EditText restTimeET;
Button addButton;

ExerciseList exerciseAdapter;
//ArrayList<Exercise> exercises;
ArrayList<Exercise> monExercises;
ArrayList<Exercise> tueExercises;
ArrayList<Exercise> wedExercises;
ArrayList<Exercise> thuExercises;
ArrayList<Exercise> friExercises;
ArrayList<Exercise> satExercises;
ArrayList<Exercise> sunExercises;
ListView exerciseList;

DatabaseReference dbExercises;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_workout);

    dbExercises = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("exercises");

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    day = intent.getStringExtra("day");

    exerciseNameET = findViewById(R.id.exerciseNameET);
    setsET = findViewById(R.id.setsET);
    repsET = findViewById(R.id.repsET);
    restTimeET = findViewById(R.id.restTimeET);
    addButton = findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    exerciseList = findViewById(R.id.exerciseList);

    //exercises = new ArrayList<>();
    monExercises = new ArrayList<>();
    tueExercises = new ArrayList<>();
    wedExercises = new ArrayList<>();
    thuExercises = new ArrayList<>();
    friExercises = new ArrayList<>();
    satExercises = new ArrayList<>();
    sunExercises = new ArrayList<>();

    //exerciseAdapter = new ExerciseList(WorkoutActivity.this, exercises);
    //exerciseList.setAdapter(exerciseAdapter);

    if(day.equals("Monday")) {
        exerciseAdapter = new ExerciseList(WorkoutActivity.this, monExercises);
    } else if(day.equals("Tuesday")) {
        exerciseAdapter = new ExerciseList(WorkoutActivity.this, tueExercises);
    } else if(day.equals("Wednesday")) {
        exerciseAdapter = new ExerciseList(WorkoutActivity.this, wedExercises);
    } else if(day.equals("Thursday")) {
        exerciseAdapter = new ExerciseList(WorkoutActivity.this, thuExercises);
    } else if(day.equals("Friday")) {
        exerciseAdapter = new ExerciseList(WorkoutActivity.this, friExercises);
    } else if(day.equals("Saturday")) {
        exerciseAdapter = new ExerciseList(WorkoutActivity.this, satExercises);
    } else if(day.equals("Sunday")) {
        exerciseAdapter = new ExerciseList(WorkoutActivity.this, sunExercises);
    }
    exerciseList.setAdapter(exerciseAdapter);

    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addExercise();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    dbExercises.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //exercises.clear();
            if(day.equals("Monday")) {
                monExercises.clear();
            } else if(day.equals("Tuesday")) {
                tueExercises.clear();
            } else if(day.equals("Wednesday")) {
                wedExercises.clear();
            } else if(day.equals("Thursday")) {
                thuExercises.clear();
            } else if(day.equals("Friday")) {
                friExercises.clear();
            } else if(day.equals("Saturday")) {
                satExercises.clear();
            } else if(day.equals("Sunday")) {
                sunExercises.clear();
            }
            for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Exercise exercise = postSnapshot.getValue(Exercise.class);
                //exercises.add(exercise);
                if(day.equals("Monday")) {
                    monExercises.add(exercise);
                } else if(day.equals("Tuesday")) {
                    tueExercises.add(exercise);
                } else if(day.equals("Wednesday")) {
                    wedExercises.add(exercise);
                } else if(day.equals("Thursday")) {
                    thuExercises.add(exercise);
                } else if(day.equals("Friday")) {
                    friExercises.add(exercise);
                } else if(day.equals("Saturday")) {
                    satExercises.add(exercise);
                } else if(day.equals("Sunday")) {
                    sunExercises.add(exercise);
                }
            }
            //exerciseAdapter.updateExerciseList(exercises);
            if(day.equals("Monday")) {
                exerciseAdapter.updateExerciseList(monExercises);
            } else if(day.equals("Tuesday")) {
                exerciseAdapter.updateExerciseList(tueExercises);
            } else if(day.equals("Wednesday")) {
                exerciseAdapter.updateExerciseList(wedExercises);
            } else if(day.equals("Thursday")) {
                exerciseAdapter.updateExerciseList(thuExercises);
            } else if(day.equals("Friday")) {
                exerciseAdapter.updateExerciseList(friExercises);
            } else if(day.equals("Saturday")) {
                exerciseAdapter.updateExerciseList(satExercises);
            } else if(day.equals("Sunday")) {
                exerciseAdapter.updateExerciseList(sunExercises);
            }
            exerciseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

addExercise() code:

```
private void addExercise() {
    String name = exerciseNameET.getText().toString();
    try {
        int sets = Integer.parseInt(setsET.getText().toString());
        int reps = Integer.parseInt(repsET.getText().toString());
        int restTime = Integer.parseInt(restTimeET.getText().toString());

        if((!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) && (!TextUtils.isEmpty(setsET.getText().toString())) && (!TextUtils.isEmpty(repsET.getText().toString())) && (!TextUtils.isEmpty(restTimeET.getText().toString()))) {
            String id = dbExercises.push().getKey();
            Exercise exercise = new Exercise(id,name,sets,reps,restTime);
            dbExercises.child(id).setValue(exercise);
            exerciseNameET.setText("");
            setsET.setText("");
            repsET.setText("");
            restTimeET.setText("");
        }
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "All fields are required. Please complete the missing fields.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Code for Exercise class:

```
public class Exercise {
private String id;
private String name;
private int sets;
private int reps;
private int restTime;

public Exercise() {}

public Exercise(String name, int sets, int reps, int restTime) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sets = sets;
    this.reps = reps;
    this.restTime = restTime;
}

public Exercise(String id, String name, int sets, int reps, int restTime) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.sets = sets;
    this.reps = reps;
    this.restTime = restTime;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getSets() {
    return sets;
}

public int getReps() {
    return reps;
}

public int getRestTime() {
    return restTime;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create simple class name DayOfWeek as below

```
static final class DayOfWeek {
    public static final int MONDAY = 0;
    public static final int TUESDAY = 1;
    //...
}
```

and in your second Activity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
index = intent.getIntExtra("position", -1);
switch (index) {
        case DayOfWeek.MONDAY:
            // your logic here
            break;
        case DayOfWeek.TUESDAY:
            // your logic here
            break;
        default:
            // case -1
            break;
}
```

**UPDATE** after added code for `addExercise()` and `Exercise` class

I think the reason is you do not compare the day you pass from MainActivity with the day which exercise in the database belong to. So that in `for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())` no matter the day equals Monday, Tuesday,... you put all same the exercise(in database) to the list.

Try my solution

1. In Exercise model class, create new field name `private String day`

   ```
   public class Exercise {
      // another fields
      private String day; // this filed save the day exercise belong to

      public Exercise(String id, String name, int sets, int reps, int restTime, String day) {
         this.id = id;
         this.name = name;
         this.sets = sets;
         this.reps = reps;
         this.restTime = restTime;
         this.day = day;
     }

     public String getDay() {
         return day;
     }
   }
   ```
2. No need to create so much `ArrayList<>()` like `monExercieses`, `tueExercises`,... That's is redundance. Only create one `ArrayList<Exercise> exercises`;
3. Now in `onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)` method

   ```
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       exercises.clear();

       for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Exercise exercise = postSnapshot.getValue(Exercise.class);
            // At the certain time, you have only one case of day ( monday, tuesday, ...)
            // You only need to compare it with the exercise in the database
           if(day.equals(exercise.getDay())) {
               exercises.add(exercise);
           }
       }

      exerciseAdapter.updateExerciseList(exercises);
      exerciseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
   ```

Hope it help !

Comment: I did something like this but instead passed a string value from the first activity. I have updated code in the question above. I am still getting the same result where no matter what day I press, the same ListView is displayed but I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Just my guesswork, the problem is due to you do not compare the day  variable with the exercise on the database. Can you show the code of addExercise() method and Exercise model class. Maybe I or other people can help.

Comment: I added the code for addExercise() method and Exercise class above. Any suggestions to help fix the problem would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated my answer, look at this and let me know either it work or not.

Comment: This worked but I also had to change my addExercise() method to create an Exercise with a String day parameter depending on the passed String parameter from the first activity. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing position why not pass a `String` value like the day(Sunday, Monday...) That way, by checking that data from the 2nd `Activity` you can determine what kind of view to setup there. You could also pass the position if you can determine the data in that position in the 1st `Activity` from the 2nd `Activity`

Feel free to ask for clarification if not clear.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to pass a string. That makes more sense to me but I'm still confused how to use that string value to setup the proper ListView.

Comment: You could use `switch` or `if` condition and assign the proper adapter to the `ListView` based on your criteria

Comment: I would also need multiple exercise ArrayLists, one for each day right? Then for the passed string value I would have to set the adapter to the corresponding ArrayList using if statements?

Comment: Seems so. If all the views has `ListView` in it, just use one `ListView` and assign different `Adapter` for different views.

Comment: I have made changes to my code above but the ListView remains blank now. I am pretty sure some of the code in the onStart() method is not correct. If you can please look at it, that would be great. Thanks.